# Как мне узнать имя pods

Tags: kubernetes

Я хочу пробросить порты

```
kubectl port-forward ...
```

Но для этого мне надо узнать имя pods, запускаю команду

```
kubectl -n main_sp get pods
```

Получаю список:

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
main-ms-hc-78469b74c-7lfdh         1/1     Running   0          13h
```

Пробую

```
kubectl port-forward main-ms-hc-78469b74c-7lfdh 8080:80
```

и получаю

```
Error from server (NotFound): pods "main-ms-hc-78469b74c-7lfdh" not found
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В команде `port-forward` тоже укажите `namespace` вашего пода:

```bsh
kubectl -n main_sp port-forward main-ms-hc-78469b74c-7lfdh 8080:80
```